# How to find 2 constants in a probability distribution function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

[image: image of a function]

How to find a and c in this function? In the example they are using limits, but I don't exactly understand why and how.

The answer is: $a = -1, c = 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $x = 1$, the cumulative distribution must be continuous with value $1$, so $a \cdot 1^2 + 2 \cdot 1 + c = 1$.  Also, at $x = 0$ the distribution must be continuous with value $0$, so $a \cdot 0^2 + 2 \cdot 0 + c = 0$.  From the second equation, $c = 0$.  Plugging into the first gives $a = -1$.

Here's the function:

[image]

Comment: So the value of x will always be the value of the function itself?

Comment: Huhhh???  No of course not!  That would mean that $f(x) = x$... a straight line.

Comment: I just realized what I've said. And I think I understood, what I wanted to ask in the first place, myself. Thanks for helping out